# How to draw one-line Venn diagram?

Tags: graphics, visualization

This is the a list of set.

```
data = {{"A"}, {"J"}, {"Q"}, {"G", "H"}, {"I", "O"},
  {"B", "C", "E", "F", "K", "N", "P"},
  {"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "K", "L", "M", "P"}}
```

If the name order from left to right is roughly A O I L D M E B C **P K F** N J H G Q, how to draw one-line Venn diragram like these?

Ps: Because the elements in the same set need to be gathered together, some adjustments may be needed to the position of the name. In this example, P K F is adjusted to F P K.

[image]

The approximate style(not using these data) is as follows
[image: In VCC]

Comment: If the first sublist is `{"A", "Q"}`, how should the venn diagram be drawn?

Comment: Please answer xzczd's question.

Comment: @xzczd Since the data and reference positions are both generated by another program and they have roughly the same index order, this will not happen. Therefore, the first sublist is {"A", "Q"} will not happen

Comment: Then if 2nd list is `{"O", "I", "E"}`, how should the venn diagram be drawn?

Comment: @xzczd Oh, the plot could not be drawn. Assuming the data can make a diagram of one-line, the question I ask is valid, so this visualization may not be very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ref = StringSplit["A O I L D M E B C P K F N J H G Q"];

pos = PositionIndex[ref];

sorteddata = SortBy[pos@*First][SortBy[pos] /@ data];

Graphics[{Text[Style[#, 32], Append[pos@#, 0]] & /@ ref, 
  MapThread[{ Opacity[.5], #2, Disk[Append[Mean[pos /@ #], 0], {Length[#]/2, 1}]} &, 
    {sorteddata, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@data]}]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Graphics[{Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], Append[pos@#, 0]] & /@ ref, 
  MapThread[{ Opacity[.5], #2, CapForm["Round"], 
     AbsoluteThickness[35], Line[Thread[{Flatten[MinMax[pos /@ #]], 0}]]} &, 
   {sorteddata, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@data]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, which wraps elements in nested colored `Frame`s depending on their set membership. It's not the prettiest, but it's easy and handles non-contiguous intersections straightforwardly.

```
data = {{"A"}, {"J"}, {"Q"}, {"G", "H"}, {"I", "O"}, {"B", "C", "E", 
   "F", "K", "N", "P"}, {"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "K", "L", "M", "P"}};

elements = "A O I L D M E B C P K F N J H G Q" // StringSplit;

colors = AssociationThread[
  data -> Map[ColorData[1], Range@Length@data]];

Row[KeyValueMap[
  Function[{element, memberships},
   Fold[Framed[#1, Background -> Lighter[#2], FrameStyle -> #2] &, 
    element, memberships]
   ],
  AssociationMap[Select[data, MemberQ[#]] & /* Map[colors], 
   elements]]];
```

[image]